# Artifact Dependencies not resolving

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0, artifacts

I have a teamcity job that publishes a single file as an artifact (this is the simplest configuration i could find that reproduces this issue)

[image]

I have another job that has this job as a snapshot dependency and an artifact dependency

[image]

The second job fails to start with the following in the logs:

```
[13:42:27]Collecting changes in 1 VCS root (2s)
[13:42:27][Collecting changes in 1 VCS root] VCS Root details
[13:42:27][VCS Root details] "xxx" {instance id=842, parent internal id=191, parent id=XXXXX, description: "GITURL.git#refs/heads/master"}
[13:42:32]Skip checking for changes - changes are already collected
[13:42:32]Clearing temporary directory: /home/centos/buildAgent/work/buildTmp
[13:42:32]Publishing internal artifacts
[13:42:32][Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [WebPublisher]
[13:42:32][Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [ArtifactsCachePublisher]
[13:42:32]Checkout directory: /home/centos/buildAgent/work/56c889e980287ca6
[13:42:32]Resolving artifact dependencies
[13:42:32][Resolving artifact dependencies] Started downloading files from <XXXX :: Build and push images, build #0.0.34 [id 256119]>
[13:42:32][Resolving artifact dependencies] Failed to resolve artifact dependency <XXXX :: Build and push images, build #0.0.34 [id 256119]>: IO exception while creating or opening temp file: No such file or directory (jetbrains.buildServer.artifacts.ResolvingFailedException)
[13:42:32]Publishing internal artifacts
[13:42:32][Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [WebPublisher]
[13:42:32][Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [ArtifactsCachePublisher]
[13:42:32]Build failed to start. Artifacts will not be published for this build
[13:42:33]Build finished
```

We have verified that the teamcity server does indeed have the necessary artifact.

When i click on "Check artifact dependencies" when configuring dependencies they resolve without issue...

```
[13:46:45]: Dependency resolving started...
[13:46:45]: Downloading artifacts from: http://tcurl:8888
[13:46:45]: Downloading teamcity-deploy.sh from <XXXX :: Build and push images, build from the same chain> to teamcity-deploy.sh; 
[13:46:45]: <XXXX :: Build and push images, build from the same chain> teamcity-deploy.sh => teamcity-deploy.sh
[13:46:45]: Dependency resolving finished successfully
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Teamcity where by the temp sub folder fails to be auto created: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-42473#tab=Comments

You can upgrade TC to v10 RC1 or move the temp folder used to one outside of the working dir and this has been proven to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Snapshot dependencies, with "Build from the same chain" selected, have a "moment in time" relation based on revision number. So the artifact needs more than to just exist, it must exist for that revision. The ability to successfully resolve from the build configuration page doesn't mean all your snapshot dependent builds will. One way to make sure your dealing with the most current revision, is from the build chain tab inside the project page that the two configurations reside in. Expand the top chain and make sure your running from the same chain. Can you see the artifact, at the success page, from the build in the same chain your getting the problem from?